# How do I reveal a file as "selected" in *nix from the command line?

Tags: linux, cross-platform, explorer, finder, window-managers

Is there a semi-universal mechanism by which to reveal files as selected in various *nix window managers via the command line?  For example, in Windows I can say the following:

```
 explorer.exe /select,C:\TestDir\TestFile.txt
```

…and Explorer will reveal the file and select it for you.  In OS X I can say the following:

```
 osascript -e 'Tell application "Finder" to reveal "MacHD:Users:myaccount:Desktop:filename.txt"'
```

…and it will do the same.  My question is, is there any way to do the exact same thing (somewhat universally) in any of the various popular *nix flavors across window managers?  Obviously "Open Containing Folder" is simple enough, but I want to go the extra step of actually opening it with the specific file selected.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't about other file managers (other answers can add that) but for nautilus [it's been recently fixed](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=a96761350ad422ec084c12f649562f9a2a83963d)

> This allows to call `nautilus
>   uri:///path/to/file` from the command
>   line to open `uri:///path/to` **with file
>   pre-selected**.

Comment: I'd still like a more "generic" solution, but given that it's window-manage dependent, I'll accept this one.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For OSX AppleScript works for all versions, but if you know you'll be dealing with 10.6 or later you'd be better served by using the -R option for "open". It's around 30 times faster.

open -R "/Volumes/Users/Desktop/file-to-open.txt"

For Linux Nautilus allows for direct calling of the file, a generic solution for GNOME (you won't find one for "Linux") is the "gnome-open" command, which currently could open the directory but won't highlight the file:

"gnome-open /tmp/file.txt"